# DES key expansion: why are these two descriptions different?

Tags: des

I would like someone to explain me how to generate DES subkeys, because in the documentation that I saw, [sometimes](http://www.commentcamarche.net/contents/crypto/des.php3) they say:

> "We rotate the initial key according to the number of iterations given by this sequence: 
>   1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 28."

and [sometimes](http://www.gaudry.be/crypto-des.html) they say:

> "The two halves are each rotated to the left by an amount depending on the iteration stage, in the following order: 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1."

Do you have any idea why these descriptions are different?

Comment: Why are you using DES?  We're not in the 70s anymore.

Comment: only, in the school, the teacher

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not going to look up the [DES key schedule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard#Key_schedule) such, but the connection between your two sequences

$$( a_i ) = ( 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 28 )$$

and

$$( b_i ) = ( 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1 )$$

is obvious: $b_i = a_i - a_{i - 1}$ (with $a_0$ taken to be 0).

That is, the second sequence gives the difference between successive elements of the first sequence.

---

**Edit:** OK, I *did* look it up, see link above.  Basically, the first sequence gives the number of bits by which the halves of the *original key* need to be rotated to obtain the $i$-th subkey, whereas the second sequence gives the number of bits by which the halves of the *previous subkey* need to be rotated to obtain the next one.  That's all there is to it.